# Unknown variables C4 and C6 when using dsolve

Tags: matlab

I just wanted to use Matlab to calculate differential equations, then I got the answer. But there were unknown vars named '**C4**' and '**C6**', and I don't know what They meant for!  Please help! Thanks!

code:

```
E = dsolve('DE = m - gama * E', 't');
I = dsolve('DI = gama * E - n * I + v * I','t');
```

res:

```
% E:
val =

(m - C4*exp(-gama*t))/gama

% I:
val =

(gama*exp(1) - C6*exp(-t*(n - v)))/(n - v)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kindly mark answers as accepted, if you think they answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To take a very simple example, DE=0.All you know, it's a constant function. That's why MATLAB will return a constant variable.

```
ans =

C1
```

You might eliminate the Conditions adding additional constrains, you can see an example opening `doc dsolve`